# Sequelize User M2M Group - Find Users that are in Groups

Tags: node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

In my project, I have Users and Groups, and a User can have multiple Groups. I'm having trouble filtering a list of users based on those who are in a certain group.

Here's my setup:

User Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const model = sequelize.define('users',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'uID',
    },
    username: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true, field: 'uEmail',
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'Users',
  });
  model.modelName = 'users';
  return model;
};
```

Group Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const model = sequelize.define('groups', {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'gID',
    },
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, field: 'gName' },
    description: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, field: 'gDescription' },
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'Groups',
  });
  model.modelName = 'groups';
  return model;
};
```

M2M Through Table :: UserGroups

```
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  const model = sequelize.define('usergroups', {
  }, {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'UserGroups',
  });
  model.modelName = 'usergroups';
  return model;
};
```

Association

```
User.belongsToMany(Group, {
  through: UserGroup,
  as: 'groups',
  foreignKey: 'uID',
});
Group.belongsToMany(User, {
  through: UserGroup,
  as: 'users',
  foreignKey: 'gID',
});
```

My db Users look like this (in shorthand):
`User1.groups = [1,2,3]`
`User2.groups = [1,3]`
`User3.groups = [2,3]`

I'm building the search rest API: `GET /users?groups[]=1&groups[]=2`

In building the query, I've tried to filter based on the groups passed in using this format:

```
let query = {};
query.include = [
  {
    model: Group,
    as: 'groups',
    where: {id: {[Op.in]: filter.groups}},
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
  },
];
const result = yield User.findAndCountAll(query);
```

or tried using `through` (with `required: true` or `required: false`):

```
let query = {};
query.include = [
  {
    model: Group,
    as: 'groups',
    through: { where: {'gID': {[Op.in]: filter.groups}}, required: true},
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
  },
];
const result = yield User.findAndCountAll(query);
```

It kinda works, except the returned objects associated groups are abbreviated. If I pass in this filter:

`GET /users?groups[]=1`

The response comes back with the right users, but the groups associated with those users are filtered:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "user1@site.com",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "My Group",
        "usergroups": {
           "uID": 1,
           "gID": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "user2@site.com",
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "My Group",
        "usergroups": {
          "uID": 2,
          "gID": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But where are groups 2 and 3 for User1, and group 2 for User2?

It's almost like I need to get all the user ids in a specific group (through the Group service class) then do:
`query.where = {id: {[Op.in]: userIdsArray}}`